# How to use ggplot together with for loop

Tags: r

When I use the code:

[image]

I can plot the graph properly with no issues.
What I need to do is to replace the y to a set of different values that will be different columns on my database "docentes_2". And for that I need to use the for loop.

Thing is that I didn't manage any way to use the for loop to chance sequentially the y value to match a different column each time the code is executed.
What i'm trying to achieve is something similar to this:

[image]

I also need to save the file each time with a different name... but that is something else.

[image]

thanks in advance guys!

I tried to past the code itself here but I kept getting the error asking to indent all code... Not sure how to do this, the ways I tried were not accepted by the post management.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Fabiano Carvalho Munhoz! Two things: (1) please no pictures of code/data, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/); (2) `ggplot2` requires to be printed to be rendered, inside of a `for` loop it is not being printed, do `gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(..)) + ...; print(gg); ggsave(gg, ...);` in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

First I had to reread my data and convert it using data.frame, after that I was able to loop around using print + ggplot. And finally I got the for loop working with ggplot.

Hopefully this helps someone in need in the future to avoid losing 5hs of life haha

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP9Hb.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste your code as text, don’t add it as an image. If you don’t know how to format code (per your question), just add it as simple text and let me know and I will edit it for you